# How to scrape and index multiple tables from one page in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops, web-scraping

I'm trying to match the district numbers with community areas in Chicago using the Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Community_areas_in_Chicago

I know how to do it table by table, but I believe there is a loop that can make this task much easier.

However, the area names are not included in the tables, so I will probably have to match them in more manual way with join or dictionaries.

The code below works, but it **scrapes** all the tables into one so I cannot distinguish the "Sides".

```
import pandas as pd

df_list = []
for i in range(0, 9): 
    url_head = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Community_areas_in_Chicago' 
    df_list.append(pd.read_html(url, header = 0)[i])

df = pd.concat(df_list).drop_duplicates()
```

1. Main task: I would like to **scrape** all the tables with an additional Index column unique for each table (Side name would be perfect). Is it possible to do it with Pandas?
2. A minor issue: There are 9 districts, however, when I use (0:8) formula the last table is missing and I have no idea why. Is there a way to automate this range with something like len?

Comment: so what exaclty would you like as the output? Also, using `read_html()` already returns the tables into a list. You don't need to iterate and append each table into a df_list

Comment: also when you slice by index [0:8], the last index value is not included. So you'd want to do [0:9], which would then include the table at index position 8

Comment: @chitown88 The desired output is a dataframe that includes Number, Community Area and the Table Number or some Id so iI can assign them to "Sides" - for example the first table would be "Central", second - "North Side" etc.

Comment: ah ok. give me a sec. I have a solution

Comment: I edited the question - I was using "community areas" instead of "Sides" and it must have been misleading.

Comment: It was slightly. So my solution might not be EXACTLY what you want. But should get you in the right direction. See below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing with `read_html()` is that it's great when you need to parse `<table>` tags, but anything outside of a `<table>` tag it won't grab. So you'll need to use BeautifulSoup to be a little more specific on how to get the data.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Community_areas_in_Chicago'
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

tables = soup.find_all('table')
results_df = pd.DataFrame()
for table in tables:
    #table = tables[0]
    main_area = table.findPrevious('h3').text.split('[')[0].strip()

    try:
        sub_area = table.find('caption').text.strip()
    except:
        sub_area = 'N/A'

    rows = table.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        #row = rows[1]
        data = row.find_all('td')

        try:    
            number = data[0].text.strip()
            com_area = data[1].text.strip()

            n_list = [ each.text.strip() for each in data[2].find_all('li') ]
            if n_list == []:
                n_list = ['']

            for each in n_list:
                temp_df = pd.DataFrame([[main_area, sub_area, number, com_area, each]], columns = ['Community area by side', 'Sub community area by side', 'Number', 'Community area', 'Neighborhoods'])

                results_df = results_df.append(temp_df).reset_index(drop=True)
        except:
            continue
```

**Output:**

```
print (results_df.to_string())
    Community area by side Sub community area by side Number          Community area                     Neighborhoods
0                  Central                        N/A     08         Near North Side                     Cabrini–Green
1                  Central                        N/A     08         Near North Side                    The Gold Coast
2                  Central                        N/A     08         Near North Side                      Goose Island
3                  Central                        N/A     08         Near North Side                  Magnificent Mile
4                  Central                        N/A     08         Near North Side                          Old Town
5                  Central                        N/A     08         Near North Side                       River North
6                  Central                        N/A     08         Near North Side                        River West
7                  Central                        N/A     08         Near North Side                     Streeterville
8                  Central                        N/A     32                    Loop                              Loop
9                  Central                        N/A     32                    Loop                      New Eastside
10                 Central                        N/A     32                    Loop                        South Loop
11                 Central                        N/A     32                    Loop                    West Loop Gate
12                 Central                        N/A     33         Near South Side                     Dearborn Park
13                 Central                        N/A     33         Near South Side                     Printer's Row
14                 Central                        N/A     33         Near South Side                        South Loop
15                 Central                        N/A     33         Near South Side  Prairie Avenue Historic District
16              North Side                 North Side     05            North Center                       Horner Park
17              North Side                 North Side     05            North Center                    Roscoe Village
18              North Side                 North Side     06               Lake View                          Boystown
19              North Side                 North Side     06               Lake View                    Lake View East
20              North Side                 North Side     06               Lake View                    Graceland West
21              North Side                 North Side     06               Lake View             South East Ravenswood
22              North Side                 North Side     06               Lake View                      Wrigleyville
23              North Side                 North Side     07            Lincoln Park                 Old Town Triangle
24              North Side                 North Side     07            Lincoln Park                         Park West
25              North Side                 North Side     07            Lincoln Park                    Ranch Triangle
26              North Side                 North Side     07            Lincoln Park               Sheffield Neighbors
27              North Side                 North Side     07            Lincoln Park              Wrightwood Neighbors
28              North Side                 North Side     21                Avondale                   Belmont Gardens
29              North Side                 North Side     21                Avondale          Chicago's Polish Village
30              North Side                 North Side     21                Avondale                   Kosciuszko Park
31              North Side                 North Side     22            Logan Square                   Belmont Gardens
32              North Side                 North Side     22            Logan Square                          Bucktown
33              North Side                 North Side     22            Logan Square                   Kosciuszko Park
34              North Side                 North Side     22            Logan Square                     Palmer Square
35              North Side             Far North side     01             Rogers Park                  East Rogers Park
36              North Side             Far North side     02              West Ridge                   Arcadia Terrace
37              North Side             Far North side     02              West Ridge                     Peterson Park
38              North Side             Far North side     02              West Ridge                  West Rogers Park
39              North Side             Far North side     03                  Uptown                        Buena Park
40              North Side             Far North side     03                  Uptown                     Argyle Street
41              North Side             Far North side     03                  Uptown                      Margate Park
42              North Side             Far North side     03                  Uptown                     Sheridan Park
43              North Side             Far North side     04          Lincoln Square                        Ravenswood
44              North Side             Far North side     04          Lincoln Square                Ravenswood Gardens 
...
```

Comment: Thank you! I will have to analyze the code for a while as I'm a Python rookie, but it's exactly what I needed.

Comment: one last question - is it possible to replace Main Community Areas (Sides) with the more detailed ones? For example divide North Side into North Side, Far North Side, Northwest Side etc.